# MVC3 connection string with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

As I have been following a MusicStore tutorial, new MVC3 project created a following connection string for me:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My model tables got created in **.\SQLEXPRESS** and all the users/roles tables are stored in the **aspnetdb.mdf** in the App_Data folder.
I would like to have the model tables and user/roles tables on my .**\SQLSERVER or localhost** rather then scattered between .\SQLEXPRESS and the mdf file. I'm struggling with the right connection string. Can anyone suggest the right one please?

**Everyone who does this has to make sure that name of the connection string should be the name of the context class derived from the **DbContext****

Comment: can you try: <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=(local); initial catalog=<yourDBName>;Integrated Security=SSPI;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: @Akhil, but what do I use for inital catalog ? The database is not there yet, it needs to be created by EF first time the application runs. I tried :  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=(local); Initial Catalog=Learn1;Integrated Security=SSPI;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> and got the following exception by asp.net : Cannot open database "Learn1" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'msi-PC\msi'.

Comment: In that case you dont need the InitialCatalog & the App=EntityFramework pieces. Does it work excluding both of them?

Comment: @Akhil, using : <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> Error:Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to run aspnet_regsql on your ApplicationServices database. You can find it in C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\4.xxx\aspnet_regsql.exe.

A default project uses ApplicationServices db as default for membership, roles, and profile. The sproc dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion is a sproc in the ASP.NET SQL Membership Provider schema.

**Response to comment #1**

Do you have a database instance running on your machine named SQLSERVER? The exception you mentioned is a common one, if asp.net cannot find the database using your connection string.

**Response to comment #2**

That makes sense. Integrated Security=true tells the connection to use the process running the MVC app (usually IIS app pool) for the sql server login. If you are testing from Visual Studio / Web Developer Express / etc, the web server is likely running on a process with your windows account. So if you can windows auth against the db server, MVC should also be able to.

[User Instances are meant for SQLEXPRESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx).

Comment: I ran aspnet_regsql on sqlexpress and it created the membership tables fine. Now I'm trying to simply change from .\SQLEXPRESS to .\SQLSERVER and get following error if I disconnect SQLEXPRESS: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

Comment: I can connect to .\SQLSERVER from Management studio using Windows authentication, and even created there a database with same name. But this connection string is not working: <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Learn1.Models.MyContext; User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient=" />, while for .\SQLEXPRESS works fine : <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Learn1.Models.MyContext; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient=" />